# AngularJS / Ruby On Rails - Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, routes

I'm new on AngularJS and RoR and i'm trying to raise my skill on them.

I'm trying to do a simple blog using this guide : http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/04/23/angularjs-on-rails-4-part-2/ and others ones but I'm currently stuck in a routing error.

Here is my rails root file :

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
    scope 'api' do
        get "posts(.:format)" => "posts#index"
        get "posts/:id(.:format)" => "posts#show"
    end
root to: "home#index"
```

And my angular one :

```
window.App = angular.module('Blog', ['ngResource']).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when ('/posts', {templateUrl: 'post-list.html.erb'}).
        otherwise ({redirectTo: '/'})
}]);
```

So i want to go to **/posts** to 'hit' the angular controller in order to load data from **/api/posts** but i got a rooting error which seems legit...

```
No route matches [GET] "/posts"
```

Any ideas on how I can get around this?

Comment: I think you meant `when ('api/posts'`

Comment: No because if i put when('api/posts'... the angular is override by ruby and i just have '[]'